# How to set text to textViews in android using loop

Tags: java, android

Here list is an array list. whats happen is the text gets over written and always displays the last value. the size of list is 4.

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i ++){
  TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_names);
  name.setText(list.get(i).toString());
  TextView email = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_emails);
  email.setText(list.get(i).toString());
}
```

Comment: It's doing that because you're pretty much asking it to...

Comment: You should be using ListView or Recyclerview. and also you shouldn't use   `TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_names);` this in a loop.

Comment: wow.. 3 people answer almost at the same time.. :v

Comment: @siddheshdighe i am using a listview. any help on how can i add text in listviews one by one

Comment: @ManishGupta check out my answer

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this solution for example:

```
private int[] food_list_dates = {
        R.id.date_1,
        R.id.date_2,
        R.id.date_3,
        R.id.date_4,
        R.id.date_5,
        R.id.date_6,
        R.id.date_7,
        R.id.date_8,
        R.id.date_9,
        R.id.date_10,
        R.id.date_11,
        R.id.date_12,
        R.id.date_13,
        R.id.date_14,
};

...

for (int i = 0; i > foodList.size(); i++) {
    ((TextView) findViewById(food_list_dates[i])).setText( i + "" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append everything.And as @siddhesh dighe mentioned don't use `TextView` initialization in loops.

```
TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_names);
TextView email = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_emails);

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i ++){
  name.append(list.get(i).toString());     
  email.append(list.get(i).toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_names);
  TextView email = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_emails);

  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i ++){
   name.append(list.get(i).toString());
   email.append(list.get(i).toString());
  }
```

Comment: thanks i am using a list view to display user name & email
your code appends name & email together in one list view
like this :
MANISHMANISHGUPTA.COM
JOHNJOHN.COM
i want it to be separate like one text view display name & other display email

Comment: @ManishGupta from where r u getting email

Comment: both from database table

Answer (score 0):

Try to use append() instead :

```
TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_names);
TextView email = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.user_emails);
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i ++){
  if(i==0)
  {
    name.append(list.get(i).toString());
    email.append(list.get(i).toString());
  }else {
    name.append("," + list.get(i).toString());
    email.append("," + list.get(i).toString());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an `ArrayList` with your data and you have a `ListView`, So you can just use `ArrayAdapter` for your `listView` and pass your Arraylist to it.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, animalsNameList);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Checkout the Complete [tutorial](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/05/populating-listview-with-arraylist.html) here